# Adding a new target

Tags: xcode, xcode4

My documentations says:

> In Xcode project, locate the "Targets" section under the "Groups &
>   Files" sidebar.  Right click on "Targets" and choose to add a new
>   target.

It even has an image of them doing it with "Targets" having a red bullseye icon.
But I don't see a bullseye anywhere.

I've got the Project Navigator open, then to the right of it is the project along with "Targets" underneath the project, but when I right click on "Targets" it only gives me:

```
Duplicate (disabled)
Delete (disabled)
Project Editor Help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are reading is out of date. Xcode 4 has changed some things. Under Xcode 4 you need to click on the top-level project at the top of the project navigator. In the project view that shows up in the main editor, you should see a project/target settings area, and right under that is a big Add Target button. Hit that button to add targets

Comment: Well, we're up to Xcode 11 now, and the "Add Target" button is no longer there. There's a list of targets on the left, with a "+" sign at the bottom. If I hit that plus sign, I get a long list of available templates, but the bullseye isn't in there.